# VB Error - An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm getting an error in a form using this code:

```
Private Sub btnCommit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click  
        ' Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure to Save this record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Save")  
        'Case MsgBoxResult.Yes  

        row = maxRows  

                txtProductID.Text = CStr(row)  

                maxRows = maxRows + 1  


                txtProductID.Text = CStr(maxRows)  

                If row <> -1 Then  

                    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(productAdapter)  

                    Dim mynewrow As DataRow  

                    mynewrow = productDataset.Tables("ProductTable").NewRow()  

                    mynewrow.Item(0) = CInt(txtProductID.Text)     
                    mynewrow.Item(1) = txtDescription.Text       
                    mynewrow.Item(2) = txtSize.Text     
                    mynewrow.Item(3) = txtQoh.Text       
                    mynewrow.Item(4) = txtUnitPrice.Text        
                    mynewrow.Item(5) = txtWarranty.Text      
            productDataset.Tables("ProductTable").Rows.Add(mynewrow)        
                    productAdapter.Update(productDataset, "ProductTable")        
                    MsgBox("Record added to database")        
                    btnCommit.Hide()        
                    btnAdd.Show()     
                    btnUpdate.Show()  
                    btnDelete.Show()  
                End If      

        '  Case MsgBoxResult.No  

        ' End Select  
    End Sub
```

The error is on the `productAdapter.Update(productDataset, "ProductTable")` line, it says

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'

occurred in System.Data.dll.

I used the same codes in another form and its working fine.

What is the problem here?

Exception Details:

{"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: An exception could be a lot of things, what is the exact error message you are getting???

Comment: @abichango has a point. Also, is there any InnerException that could give more information?

Comment: Items 3,4 and 5 look like numerics, but you are pushing text to it.

Comment: Exception Details:

{"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: @Plutonix I added CInt to items 3,4 and 5 and still the same error.

Comment: The details clearly indicates there is something wrong with the SQL, but the query isnt shown

Comment: @Plutonix The only SQL query that I have is sql = "Select * FROM Product" to load the data to the text boxes.

Comment: `productAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText` will give you the SQL if it was built by commandbuilder or the wizard.  Also with `SELECT *` you have no idea if the order is as you expect.  You could be stuffing a name into a date column.